# Keras throws a DisconnectedInputError due to custom loss function

Tags: neural-network, theano, keras

I am trying to implement the regularization term for the Norm of the Gradient for [improved WGAN training](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00028.pdf) in Keras with theano backend. Basically I want to penalize the l2 Norm of the Gradient based on how far away it is from 1.

I am implementing a custom loss like this:

```
def get_gradient_norm(model, y_pred):
    weights = model.trainable_weights
    gradients = model.optimizer.get_gradients(K.mean(y_pred), weights)
    acc = None
    for g in gradients:
        s = K.sum(K.square(g))
        if acc == None:
            acc = s
        else:
            acc = s + acc
    return K.sqrt(acc)

def make_w_reg_loss(model):
    lvar = K.variable(lamb, name="Lambda")

    def foo(y_true, y_pred):
        gnorm = get_gradient_norm(model, y_pred)
        return lvar * K.square(gnorm - 1)

return foo

[...]

critic.compile(loss=make_w_reg_loss(critic), optimizer=RMSprop(learn_rate))
```

It throws a DisconnectedInputError once the training process tries to attempt to get the gradient of my custom loss function.

Why?

Replacing the loss with some standard loss works. The error is something about the loss function I defined.

See this gist for [a minimal not-working example](https://gist.github.com/ColaColin/1a8c7ef9a76a96a3868756bbaafbd4a0) of my attempt

EDIT:

So I think I know how to make it work now.
First I just randomly added this term to my loss, directly before returning it from foo(y_true, y_pred):

```
K.mean(y_pred) - K.mean(y_pred)
```

Clearly a constant zero, and if I only use this term as my loss I do get a zero.
If however I add this "constant zero" to my regularization loss it suddenly works fine. I get a loss, which is non-zero so comes from the regularization, and optimization over many train_on_batch does reduce the loss as well.

So is this an odd issue with theano being a bit overzealous in throwing exceptions? My question still stands: Why does it throw in the original code. Since adding a constant zero term fixes it, it looks like a bug to me?

Answer (score 0):

I really would like to implement this improved wgan in keras too, and I'm surprised to see how you solved your "issue". Did you verify trought experiments that your wgan-gp loss is working as intended?
It should be easy to check, it is a so stable training that enable you the use of very deep discriminator ;)
I would like to do the same work done by you but with tensorflow backend, and I will try looking at your code and the code here: [keras improved wgan](https://github.com/rarilurelo/keras_improved_wgan)

I will be happy to hear your updates, I'll write again here as soon as I have a working code of wgan-gp in keras/tensorflow! 
P.S. the link above is implementing all the procedure in tensorflow code, forcing to use the tf training functions. I really like your approach, where we can simply define a keras loss, using all of our usual keras high level API for training ;)

edit: from your code you seems to work totally with K backend, so your code should easily run with tensorflow backend too. Did you try changing the backend to check if the issue/bug is truly related to Theano?

2nd edit: you are calculating the gradient w.r.t the weights, but the in the wgan-gp paper the gradient penalty is calculated starting from gradient w.r.t the average samples between generated and real samples. This would bring very different results.
In the following link you can find a very nice improved wgan loss implementation, that *could* work on theano too:
https://github.com/farizrahman4u/keras-contrib/

Comment: The code I posted is a brutally cut down version and certainly does not correctly implement anything, it was just meant to show the issue.
My real code implements the sampling by passing in interpolated datapoints between real and fake samples. I've only tested the toy examples so far, but they looked promising to me. Got sidetracked with more "real" work however, so I could not test out more complex datasets.

Comment: I did not test with tensorflow, have no install of it here, since the final loss function contains a lot more terms the exception-issue isn't really a problem either way. It just confused me.

I'd guess the wgan implementation you posted probably is written by people with more experience in keras anyway and better documented. I might just use that one when I come back to that, as it seems to implement the interpolation part on the GPU, I was doing it in CPU. Cool!

Comment: I ended up losing 12 hours on debugging, trying to modify the code I linked in order to work as a separate gradient penalty loss(instead of integrated into discriminator) and I soon stuck on the wall "tensorflow is getting None as loss" type of error. The I suddenly remember your fix, and well, is fixing in my case too. Without your fix, if I visualize the model via model.summary(), there is no input layer. With your simple fix, suddenly the input layer appear as input (and the gradient penalty loss works without giving None error)

Comment: So, what seems to be happening, both with theano and Keras(at the best of my limited backend knowledge), is that the graph compiler is not correctly linking all the dumbo license variables, ending with a disconnected graph. Putting y_pred on the loss function "return" line is incredibly fixing the issue as the graph is correctly built. That could be the strangest bug/issue(and fix!) of my life, ever!